# Does Shen using his ultimate on a character in stealth show either?

Tags: league-of-legends

I had a surprise visit from Shen when fighting against Shaco. Shaco used his Deceive to become stealth and then suddenly ninjas. I suddenly had a Shen taunting me while Shaco stabbed me to death.

Did I just miss the Shen approaching or is stealth a way to hide Shen jumping to a person?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you did not miss Shen approaching. You can teleport to an invisible teammate without making them visible.

I used to do this quite often with Evelynn + Shen back when she was still viable.

Comment: Wow, that's dirty. Shaco Jungle plus Shen top could result in a 3 man gank mid or 4 man bot.

Comment: yes very dirty. you could do the same with teleporting to wards i believe but this was quite some time ago.

Comment: Indeed, though they've since made wards always show the teleport graphic, even through fog of war.

Comment: Are you trying to say Eve isn't viable anymore?

Comment: Yes Evelynn wasn't viable back then. (this was pre revamp)