# Can Shen teleport Fiora around the map?

Tags: league-of-legends

Assuming they are on opposite teams, if Fiora uses her ultimate on a Shen that is channeling his ultimate does the Fiora end up with the Shen at his new location?

Comment: Sounds like its time for some SCIENCE! General observations have shown that teleporters will tag along with a target regardless of the distance they have moved as long as they were within range when selected as the target. However, I have not tried the exact setup you have listed above so can not post as an answer.

Comment: I'm betting the Fiora will end up with the Shen, but I haven't had a chance to do the science.

Comment: I know that Leona can tag along with Twisted Fate if she hits him with the sword throw right as TF is about to port away, I've done it myself, hilarious when it happens. As long as no one else was around Shen and as long as Fiora's ult didn't finish before he finished ulting to someone I would have to say yes, absolutely.

Comment: I'm gonna say false, and say she just stops her ulti wasting it. It is like vladimirs pool, if he uses it and is the first target and thus also the last it stops the ulti.

Comment: Hopefully it drops her in some sort of voidspace with Malzahar and he just beats the hell out of her for eternity. (I hate Fiora)

Comment: Maybe this question will help, If I'm finishing a recall and the 1 second or so at the end I can get hit w/o being interrupted, if Fiora starts her ulti on me will she end up back in my base as the last hit also has to be on me? ;)

Comment: Shouldn't be possible if you don't have vision of Shen after he ults: http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=21693616#post21693616

Comment: well.. Whats about Warwick? Same like Fioras for his ultimate?

Comment: Warwick's ultimate is a suppression effect so you are unable to cast summoner spells. Fiora's ultimate has no innate CC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer is now out of date due to recent rework of Fiora. See [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56085/can-shen-teleport-fiora-around-the-map/255743#255743) for updated information.

Yes, but only if Fiora has vision on Shen's ultimate location. The latest Rift Myths just answered this question for us:
[If Fiora uses her ultimate on Twisted Fate while he is channeling his ultimate will she teleport with him?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=OLAQ0KCiw0k#t=35s)

It turns out it is based on if you have visibility of where he is teleporting. The first test shows that Fiora will not move with TF if she does not have vision on his final location. The second test she does move because she has vision on the final location.

This also lines up with [what Micheal Ayers tested with Nunu](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/56102/274).

Comment: I Send a message to them and ask to do so. Better quality =D

Comment: REALLY nice video +1 =)

Comment: Now i got a question, idk if i should create a post for this or not... so i will ask here first. What happen if i use flash for a fog area while fiora is ultimating ?? i escape from her ult ? If u think that this can be another question, i will make one.

Comment: The champion spotlight showed her following people that flash so she would just move along with them.

Comment: This no longer works as of the fiora update. Consider editing this to reflect that

Answer (score 3):

As of Fiora's champion update in August of 2015, this mechanic no longer works, as her abilities have been reworked and significantly changed. None of Fiora's new abilities will cause her to follow a teleport/shen ult/tf ult, or similar mechanic.

Answer (score -10):

### Update

*With regard to the other answers tests and new found description*

The League of Legends wikia has other description for Fiora's ultimate that says:

> Blade Waltz is a targeted multiple target ability that deals physical damage to enemy champions **within range of the initial target**. Fiora will strike five times at random champions, the first and last strike will be on the same target. Successive hits on the same target will deal reduced damage. (see [[1](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Fiora_the_Grand_Duelist/Ability_Details)])

This description, if correct, just say it all.

#### Case 1: You target a hero that is not Shen,

then you will hit 5 targets in range of this hero that may include Shen. If Shen is in range, he will get instantly hit. If by any synchronisation odds Shen did port just between the target selection and the hit, we can assume he will still be hit at his new position, but Fiora will get back to the original location as soon as she selected the new target which will be in range of the first initial target.

#### Case 2: You target Shen ultiing.

You get 1 hit on Shen, then 3 random hits on targets around Shen. In the same manner if there is no synchronisation odds you will hit only targets in the battlefield where Shen is. If you have a synchronisation shift you may hit one target on the first battlefield when Shen has already moved. All other targets will be in the second battlefield.

---

### Historic

It is impossible to answer this question. All depends on the implementation of the algorithms by Riot Games.

Nevertheless we can state that Fiora should not select a target as valid if it is more than "Range: 400" away, which is her ultimate range.
The other rule in Fiora's utl says that the first and last target is the same. If Shen gets ult first, that rule may override the range limitation.

Good to be know, as Janna I once casted my bird on a recalling champion, he ended up heading toward the fountain despite the range.

With regard to these consideration, I will assess that Fiora could port with Shen in the following conditions:

1. She ults him first and Shen ports while Fiora's ult targets the other 3 targets

I think that Shen being regarded as a valid position just before he finishes TP is not a valid case because that would mean that Fiora's algorithm is looking for Shen position gets the old position, acknowledges the position, then retrieve the position AGAIN and gets the new one. That could happen only if the algorithm is implemented as this: select a valid Champion then ask for position. In this case, the synchronisation could end up with a target being "followed" while porting.

Anyway, only insight of the source code or testing could reveal the behaviour.

Comment: It is not impossible to answer this question. It can be answered through experimentation.

Comment: Citing myself : "Anyway, only insight of the source code or testing could reveal the behaviour.". That first sentence is intended to be some warning about the provided answer. By the way, even if it can be tested, the behaviour might also be a bug that will be solved afterward. So whatever the answer is, it's still dependent of the game design and this answer can only be an attempt to explain this, explaining why I put that sentence here. Any answer here is speculation unless sated otherwise by Riot and I make it clear at the beginning.

Comment: By that logic, [any](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/51500/does-shen-using-his-ultimate-on-a-character-in-stealth-show-either) [mechanical](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54921/would-ahris-charm-slow-down-master-yi-while-he-is-using-his-ultimate) [question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53466/tiamat-stacking) is unanswerable. Nevermind that, whether or not it is a bug, it doesn't change the fact that *that is how it operates*.

Comment: I'll take it a step further. By that logic, *every single question on this site* is unanswerable.

Comment: This is false. Many mechanicals are describe and well documented by game designers on site and or official forums threads. Nevertheless I understand the needs of this question and that's why I did not flagged it as too localized or else and tried to provide insight based on actual facts. Since there is no official statement on the matter, I stated it not to induce someone in error. I will be happy to welcome any experimental answers and or future official answer. Until one knows exactly what happens, I feel that my answer still stands by its reasoning. But it's your right to disregard it.

Comment: This is not a Bug and its how the ability works. ALL abilities that follow one champion if he FLASH or TELEPORT WILL get dragged as well if he use some SKILL with the same function. As I said in my answer, using Xin, and Fiora as example. I did the attack with XIN myself in a real game. and now with the Fiora and some friends

Comment: Understand your point @M'vy , and it can be tested. But will take more that one footage. `On WoW, you could saw a lot of tests with procs of 1% and everything around this, but those tests took thousands or try and error`