# What happens to a Maokai who uses twisted advanced on a teleporting target?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that Maokai's twisted advanced follows people who flash and use any displacement effects but does it follow Twisted Fate's ultimate?

What about other teleportation effects such as Recall or the teleport summoner spell?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Shen teleport Fiora around the map?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56085/can-shen-teleport-fiora-around-the-map)

Answer (score 2):

Just like teleporting he will not follow you even if he is in mid graphic about to root you.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on WHERE Twisted Fate is teleporting to. Works like Fiora's ultimate on Twisted Fate.

and this

Answer (score 0):

Depending on when maokai casted his skill when TF activated his ult.

Just like backing "b" even if you do damage, if i think 9/10 of the animation is complete, the damage/stun is negated and doesnt affect the user.

So in this case, i believe if used early, it will cancel TF's ult
If casted too late, the stun animation will appear on TF in the fountain but maokai will not follow or will his skill have any effect.

Answer (score -1):

I would stop in the area TF ulti'd to. It does not work on global ultimates the way it would against a flash.

source:

Maokai wiki:
http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Maokai_the_Twisted_Treant/Ability_Details